# I can't find nodes in my XFDL document using XPath

Tags: java

I know similar questions have been answered but they don't quite address my specific problem:

```
public String getValue(String xPath) {
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    xpath.setNamespaceContext(new PersonalNamespaceContext());
    String value = null;
    NodeList nodes = null;
    try {
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(xPath);
        nodes = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("nodes: " + nodes.getLength());
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int idx = 0; idx < nodes.getLength(); idx++) {
        value = nodes.item(idx).getTextContent();
        System.out.println(value);
        //break;
    }
    return value;
}
```

I need to be able to get the value of a "visible" text node.

```
                 <itemlocation>
                    <x>0</x>
                    <y>0</y>
                 </itemlocation>
                 <visible>off</visible>
              </pane>
```

I can't seem to find the correct xPath value to do it. Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed the XPath that you're currently using. Especially since you set a namespace context, but your XML doesn't show a namespace.

Comment: And it's unclear what "the value" of a "visible" node is. I'm assuming that it's not "off", so what is it? Is it the concatenated text under `pane`? Or the `itemLocation` XML? Or something completely different?